# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geo'

Tags: geo

I am using the following libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import googlemaps
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import sys
from dateutil import parser
from geo import *
import re
```

I already installed in the prompt:

```
pip install GoogleMaps 
pip install geopy
pip install geopandas
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

However, I am still having the following error:

```
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-1-456abdb5bc33> in <module>
>       5 import sys
>       6 from dateutil import parser
> ----> 7 from geo import *
>       8 import re
```

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geo'`

I really appreciate any help to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
pip install geo-py
```

?

https://pypi.org/project/geo-py/